# Catching exceptions raised in the greenlets

Tags: python, exception, gevent, greenlets

I'm trying to catch the exceptions raised within the greenlets. According to [this tutorial](http://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/), unfortunately 'exceptions raised in the Greenlet, stay inside the Greenlet'. In the code below, I have a sync method which spawns crawl greenlets. Those crawl greenlets raise HTTPError exception, which I need to catch in the body of sync method. Based on the exception, in the sync method I will set the appropriate status of the Account object. Any idea how can I catch exceptions raised in greenlets in the sync method in order to accomplish that? Thank you in advance!

```
# this is standalone helper method
def crawl(item):
    try:
        item.refresh_children(False) # THROWS HTTPError exception
        greenlets = [gevent.spawn_link_exception(crawl, child) for child in item.children]
        gevent.joinall(greenlets)
    except HTTPError, e:
        print e.message
        raise e
    except (JSONDecodeError, InvalidCredentialsException) as e:
        print e.message
        raise e

# this is instance method of the Account class 
def sync(self):
    "Sync search index with data from source"
    try:
        greenlets = [gevent.spawn_link_exception(crawl, item) for item in self.get_navigation()]
        gevent.joinall(greenlets)
        self.date_synced = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.save()
    except HTTPError, e:
        if e.status_code == 401:
            self.status = 'revoked'
        else:
            self.status = 'error'
        self.save()
    except LinkedFailed, e:
        print e.message
        exception_name = e.message.split()[-1]
        if exception_name in ['HTTPError', 'JSONDecodeError']:
            self.status = 'error'
            self.save()
        elif exception_name == 'InvalidCredentialsException':
            self.status = 'revoked'
            self.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

Greenlets will hold the results of the function spawned for the greenlet or the exception, if one was raised. You can get the result, or re-raise the exception, with the [`get`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html#gevent.Greenlet.get) method. 
Since you seem to be changing the status based on any of the greenlets erroring the sync method would wind up looking something like:

```
def sync(self):
    "Sync search index with data from source"
    greenlets = [gevent.spawn_link_exception(crawl, item) for item in self.get_navigation()]
    gevent.joinall(greenlets)
    try:
        results = [greenlet.get() for greenlet in greenlets]
    except HTTPError, e:
        if e.status_code == 401:
            self.status = 'revoked'
        else:
            self.status = 'error'
        self.save()
    except LinkedFailed, e:
        print e.message
        exception_name = e.message.split()[-1]
        if exception_name in ['HTTPError', 'JSONDecodeError']:
            self.status = 'error'
            self.save()
        elif exception_name == 'InvalidCredentialsException':
            self.status = 'revoked'
            self.save()

    self.date_synced = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.save()
```